# CakePHP 3.x - add() function throws error

Tags: php, cakephp, entity

Having the table

**adresses_users** in my Database contains:

```
id | user_id | adress_id
```

**Function add in my AdressesUsersController.php**

```
public function add()
    {
        $adressesUser = $this->AdressesUsers->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $adressesUser = $this->AdressesUsers->patchEntity($adressesUser, $this->request->data);
            if ($this->AdressesUsers->save($adressesUser)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The adresses user has been saved.'));

                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error(__('The adresses user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
        $this->set(compact('adressesUser'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['adressesUser']);
    }
```

**Getting this Error**

> *Error: Call to a member function newEntity() on boolean  File C:\xampp\htdocs\uh\src\Controller\AdressesUsersController.php*

I baked the controller and model - so I don´t get whats wrong.
I have a working app where I compared - seems legit :/

EDIT:

```
<?php
namespace App\Model\Table;

use App\Model\Entity\AdressesUser;
use Cake\ORM\Query;
use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

/**
 * AdressesUsers Model
 *
 * @property \Cake\ORM\Association\BelongsTo $Users
 * @property \Cake\ORM\Association\BelongsTo $Adresses
 *
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\AdressesUser get($primaryKey, $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\AdressesUser newEntity($data = null, array $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\AdressesUser[] newEntities(array $data, array $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\AdressesUser|bool save(\Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface $entity, $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\AdressesUser patchEntity(\Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface $entity, array $data, array $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\AdressesUser[] patchEntities($entities, array $data, array $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\AdressesUser findOrCreate($search, callable $callback = null)
 */
class AdressesUsersTable extends Table
{

    /**
     * Initialize method
     *
     * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
     * @return void
     */
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->table('adresses_users');
        $this->displayField('id');
        $this->primaryKey('id');

        $this->belongsTo('Users', [
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
        $this->belongsTo('Adresses', [
            'foreignKey' => 'adress_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Default validation rules.
     *
     * @param \Cake\Validation\Validator $validator Validator instance.
     * @return \Cake\Validation\Validator
     */
    public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
    {
        $validator
            ->integer('id')
            ->allowEmpty('id', 'create');


        return $validator;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a rules checker object that will be used for validating
     * application integrity.
     *
     * @param \Cake\ORM\RulesChecker $rules The rules object to be modified.
     * @return \Cake\ORM\RulesChecker
     */
    public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
    {
        $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['user_id'], 'Users'));
        $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['adress_id'], 'Adresses'));

        return $rules;
    }
}
```

**Before my Controller Class**

```
/**
 * AdressesUsers Controller
 *
 * @property \App\Model\Table\AdressesUsersTable $AdressesUsers
 */
```

Comment: Maybe the Table name does not matches the controller name, can you please post the Table object definition?

Comment: @RohitAilani No, entity class names are by convention singular.

Comment: Yes. All the other entities are singular too.

Comment: @RohitAilani, no, the enity is singular. He also said that the code is baked. Maybe clearing the cache could help?

Comment: `false` is being returned by the magic getter in case there is a mismatch between the property name and (the class part of) `$this->modelClass`. **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.3.5/src/Controller/Controller.php#L345-L348**

Comment: Yes I realized that and have removed the comment, thanks for noting it @ndm

Comment: I already cleaned the Cache in the debugKit

Comment: @ndm I can´t see a missmatch tho ?

Comment: I'd have to see that with my own eyes to believe it ;)

Comment: I´m a little confused here. So is there a mistake already? Do you need more code? I thought it is just model, controller and view(template) - but there seems no problem.

Comment: Is it because I used **adress** instead of **address**?

Comment: Going crazy. Well since I already wasted 3-4 hours on this I rather just use the loadModel - before I waste any more time... copied exactly the whole MVS from a working app - still nothing.

Comment: @ndm how do I bake HABTM anyways? I couldn´t find it in the docs. I tried AdressesUsers and adresses_users

Comment: if you use loadModel as suggested by RohitAilani Answer does it works? I know it should not be necessary but it's just for curiosity. Also what do you get if in your controller you do `debug($this->modelClass)`?

Comment: Yes, if I use it - everything works. But as u mentioned that should be necessary and there is something wrong with the naming convention (as ndm stated) - can´t figure out where tho. I will try the debug when I get home, only got it on lhost so far

Comment: I feel dumb as shit -.- I called the wrong controller! always used myapp/addressesusers/add etc. gotta use adresses-users instead. Damn! Thanks @all for the help. When you see me, give me a slap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
public function add()
    {

        $this->loadModel('AdressesUsers');
        $adressesUser = $this->AdressesUsers->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {

            if ($this->AdressesUsers->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The adresses user has been saved.'));

                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error(__('The adresses user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
        $this->set(compact('adressesUser'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['adressesUser']);
    }
```

Comment: Why do I have to load the Model? Shouldn´t that be included anyways in my Controller? o.O

I got a view now - without users and adresses list though.

Comment: It should either be there in your beforeFilter function of the controller or if it is not there then you need to add it here and as your error shows that you are missing the model. So, I provided you with this.